# IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

Can somebody explain to me why I'm getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity when trying to click the button to get data from database?

my xml code has an onClick like this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClick_DeleteAll"/>
```

my mainactivity code:

```
public void onClick_DeleteAll(View view){
    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(getApplicationContext())
    float total = dbTools.total();
}
```

my database class(DBTools.java) code:

```
public float total(){
    float total = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Sum("+ PRICE +") FROM " + TABLE_ITEM_SELL, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        total = Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(0));
    }

    return total;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong because It only happens when the method that I try to execute will return data. Like the code above, it returns float.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)
            at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
            at com.jcarlapp.carl.amystore.DBTools.total(DBTools.java:151)
            at com.jcarlapp.carl.amystore.MainActivity.onClick_DeleteAll(MainActivity.java:306)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can You please post the stacktrace (logcat output)? I think You have a database problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by `NPE`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)
            at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
            at com.jcarlapp.carl.amystore.DBTools.total(DBTools.java:151)
```

It seems like `cursor.getString(0)` returns `null` in method total.

I assume that you have no rows in the table to calculate sum.

Comment: but it will still return zero, right? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: It says null not zero, you have to check if it null or not.

Comment: select sum(x) from table_x returns always a row but if there no data rows, "sum(x)" can be null!

Comment: I got it! I never thought sqlite is a little different. Because in other sql (ex. mssql), it still return zero I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the table doesn't contain any data, `SUM(column)` will return SQL `NULL`.

`getString()` on a `NULL` column value will return Java `null`.

`parseFloat(null)` causes the exception.

Consider checking for a null value before trying to parse it.